# lauch problems; ResourceNotFound

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rosws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello after executing the lauch file i got the following problems:

```
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 257, in main
    p.start()
  
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 257, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 206, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()
  
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 121, in _load_config
    self.config = roslaunch.config.load_config_default(self.roslaunch_files, self.port, verbose=self.verbose)
 
 File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 421, in load_config_default
    loader.load(f, config, verbose=verbose)
 
 File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 694, in load
    self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)
  
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 666, in _load_launch
    self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)
  
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 601, in _recurse_load
    n = self._node_tag(tag, context.child(''), ros_config, default_machine, verbose=verbose)
  
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 347, in _node_tag
    self.opt_attrs(tag, context, ('machine', 'args', 'output', 'respawn', 'cwd', 'launch-prefix', 'required'))
 
 File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 178, in opt_attrs
    return [self.resolve_args(tag_value(tag,a), context) for a in attrs]
  
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 159, in resolve_args
    return substitution_args.resolve_args(args, context=context.resolve_dict, resolve_anon=self.resolve_anon)
  
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 203, in resolve_args
    resolved = _find(resolved, a, args, context)
  
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 139, in _find
    return resolved[0:idx-len(arg)] + r.get_path(args[0]) + resolved[idx:]
  
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/rospkg/rospack.py", line 149, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)

ResourceNotFound: pow_analyzer

ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros

ROS path [1]=/home/bojan/ros_workspace/gps_common

ROS path [2]=/home/bojan/ros_workspace/lse_xsens_mti

ROS path [3]=/home/bojan/ros_workspace/cereal_port

ROS path [4]=/home/bojan/ros_workspace/scan_tools

ROS path [5]=/home/bojan/ros_workspace/utils

ROS path [6]=/home/bojan/ros_workspace/pow_analyzer

ROS path [7]=/home/bojan/ros_workspace/amcl_listener

ROS path [8]=/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/pow_analyze

ROS path [9]=/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/amcl_listener

ROS path [10]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

ROS path [11]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share

ROS path [12]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros

ROS path [13]=/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/gps_umd

ROS path [14]=/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/cereal_port

ROS path [15]=/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/lse_xsens_mti

ROS path [16]=/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/scan_tools/csm

ROS path [17]=/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher

ROS path [18]=/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher

ROS path [19]=/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher

ROS path [20]=/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher

Any Help?

this is the launch file 

<launch>

<node name="rosplay" pkg="rosbag" type="play" args="~/Desktop/PowRos/Data/User1/pow_freek_1_2011-04-01-14-17-41.bag             --clock"/>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="baselink_laser" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 10"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_imu" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /laser /base_imu 10"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="baselink_camera" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /camera 10"/>

<!-- Start the map server node and specify the map file (*.pgm) and the map resolution in metres/pixel -->
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find amcl_listener)/maps/pow_real_time.yaml"         output="screen"/>

<!--Start the Laser_scan_matcher package, to provide odometry from laser data (ICP)-->
<node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" 
    name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">
    <param name="use_alpha_beta" value="true"/>
    <param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>
</node>

<!-- Start the gmapping node -->
<!--node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen"/-->

<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" respawn="true" output="screen">
    <param name="base_frame_id" value="base_link"/>
    <param name="odom_frame_id" value="world"/>
    <param name="global_frame_id" value="map"/>
    <param name="update_min_d" value="0.09"/>   
    <param name="update_min_a" value="0.09"/> 
    <param name="initial_pose_x" value="-1"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_y" value="0"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_a" value="-0.1"/>
    <param name="min_particles" value="6000"/> 
    <param name="max_particles" value="8000"/>
    <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>
    <param name="kld_err" value="0.1"/> 
    <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.2"/>   
    <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_max_beams" value="30"/>
</node>

<!--Start the "analyzer_packages"-->
<!-- acml_listener broadcasts markers for the position of the wheelchair, to visualize in Rviz-->
<node pkg="amcl_listener" type="amcl_pose_listener" name="amcl_listener" output="screen"/>
<!-- Object node records minimal ranges from laser, speed_node will record travel speed of wheelchair -->
<node pkg="pow_analyzer" type="object_node" name="object_node" output="screen"/>
<node pkg="pow_analyzer" type="speed_node" name="speed_node" output="screen"/>

<!-- Start an rviz node with a custom configuration for the viewpoint, map_server, trajectory, laser scans, etc -->
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" output="screen" name="rviz" args="-d $(find pow_analyzer)/launch/pow_rviz.vcg"/>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37826/lauch--problems;-resourcenotfound/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-07-03

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-03**:
roscd pow_analyzer is not working: But I installed and compiled perfectly the package.I had to install 6 packages and done it manually so , every time installed the package i cjanged the path. also rospack find pow_analyzer failed. So every time I installed new package I changed the package path:

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-03**:
Ok. I solve that but I need like 7 packages for this launch file. So how to install all in same package path? I need the followings packages: amcl_listener, pow_analyzer, gps_common, cereal_port, lse_xsens_mti, csm, laser_scan_matcher. So there are 2 internal and 5 external packages.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-03**:
because i got other error:ResourceNotFound: amcl_listener
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/pow_analyzer    So how to create a package path for 7 packages???

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-03**:
I download all 7 packages from one ftp server and put on one folder my ubuntu Desktop . So I put them on  ~/Desktop/PowRos/utils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a problem with your launch file but that roslaunch cannot find the package `pow_analyzer`. Is the package in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. You can verify that your ROS environment is set up correctly by either doing a `roscd pow_analyzer` which must work or by executing:

```
rospack find pow_analyzer
```

which must print the path to the package pow_analyzer. If one of the commands fails, `pow_analyzer` is not in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSouni](https://answers.ros.org/users/71585/rosouni/) on 2021-04-12**:
I successfully use this command to find my package but the error still exists which confuses me a lot.

```
ouni@ouni-VirtualBox:~/Code/ugv_ws$ rospack find rslidar_pointcloud
/home/ouni/Code/ugv_ws/src/ros_rslidar/rslidar_pointcloud
part of my launch file is as follows:
  <arg name="lidar_param_path" default="$(find rslidar_pointcloud)/data/rs_lidar_16/"/>
```

and the error:

```
Resource not found: The following package was not found in <arg default="$(find 
rslidar_pointcloud)/data/rs_lidar_16/" name="lidar_param_path"/>: rslid
ar_pointcloud
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/ouni/Code/learning_ros/test_service/src
ROS path [2]=/home/ouni/文档/pcl_test/src文档/pcl_test/src
ROS path [3]=/home/ouni/Code/pcl_test/src
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/melodic/share
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

appreciated for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is a variable with many entries, separated by ':'.

You should use the tool rosws to manage such environments. Your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH should be (I guess):

```
/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/gps_umd:/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/cereal_port:/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/lse_xsens_mti:/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/scan_tools/csm:/home/bojan/Desktop/PowRos/utils/scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
```

if that is where you put your stuff.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-09-25**:
ok solve it. Thanks